# SCNScene initialization from file crashes on macOS Ventura

Tags: crash, scenekit, macos-ventura

This is pretty unusual, because I'm unable to replicate the issue on macOS Monterey. I have a SCNScene object that is initialized in viewDidLoad as such:

```
scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/preview.scn")!
```

And as you can see below, the file exists in my project's Resources under the appropriate path:
[image]

As previously mentioned, the crash does not occur in builds created under macOS Monterey. Did something change in the resource file path's API?

So far I have tried to initialize using a different way of creating the URL, like so:

```
scene = try! SCNScene(url: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "art.scnassets/preview", withExtension: "scn")!)
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. Reset the path to Command Line Tools**

To fix this issue, install the latest version of `Command_Line_Tools` for Xcode 14.1 and then execute these two commands in zsh Terminal (password is required):

```bash
sudo xcode-select --reset
```

---

```bash
sudo xcode-select -switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

Restart your Mac.

---

**2. Renaming process**

Rename the `art.scnassets` to `artist.scnassets` if the above steps still do not help.